# c# ews List<searchFilter> error

Tags: c#, reference, exchangewebservices

I have recently tried to write an application in c# using EWS to read the contents of an exchange mailbox. I have the login working (im 90% sure of this) but when i try to use examples from online on how to display the content of the inbox i am greeted with the errors "The type or namespace 'searchfilter' could not be found. (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Usually this means i just need to add the reference to my project, however i already have Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices added as a reference. Anyone seen this issue before? Any ideas?

using:
windows 7
visual studio 2010
.net 4 is installed but my target framework is 3.5

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices;
    using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
    using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Xml;
```

Comment: That's odd - [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.searchfilter.aspx) says that's where it is. Could you try looking inside Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.dll using object explorer, or [reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) (or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) or whichever's the free-decompiler-of-choice), to see if it's actually there?

Comment: Thank you but asawyer was correct that it was my capitalization that was the problem. stupid mistake on my part but thats what a second set of eyes is for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is a direct copy/paste of the error message, have you checked that your capitalization is correct? It should be "SearchFilter" not "searchfilter"

Here is the msdn reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.searchfilter(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the right Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices assembly, 1.0 or 1.1 could be different.

Comment: Thank you but asawyer was correct that it was my capitalization that was the problem. stupid mistake on my part but thats what a second set of eyes is for :)